# From inside a function, how can I have access to an expression used in its call?

Tags: r, dplyr, substitution

Inside a function, I want to use the name of the object used in the call. For instance, if I am testing identity between objects `foo` and object `bar`, I want to be able to print 2 want to be able to print:

`foo is not the same as bar`

even though my function is defined with other names for the parameters.

I know how to do this using `substitute`. Unfortunately, `substitute` breaks in several cases: when chaining functions with `dplyr`'s `%>%`; or more generally when a function call in the first place.

```
test.equal <- function(a, b) if(!identical(a,b)) cat(
  substitute(a),
  'is not the same as',
  substitute(b)
)
object1 <- 'lkjlkj'
object2 <- 1:10
test.equal(object1, object2)    # works as intended
object1 %>% test.equal(object2) # does not : prints '.' for object 1
test.equal(object1, object2^2)  # error: cat does not print 'language'
                                # and if we use as.character to force evaluation...

test.equal2 <- function(a, b){
  charb <- as.character(substitute(b))
  if(!identical(a,b)) cat(
   substitute(a),
   'is not the same as',
   charb
  )
}

test.equal2(object1, object2^2) # prints ^ object2 2 instead of object2^2
```

What is the proper way to use write my function?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no clean way to do what you want due to the way that `%>%` works

Answer (score -1):

This is achieved via  `deparse(substitute(a))` , which will return the name of the variable (`foo`) you entered in the function call.

Comment: This still would return "." for the variable name in the dplyr chain.

Comment: it is a partial answer: it resolves the problem with `test.equal(object1, object2^2)` but not with `object1 %>% test.equal(object2)test`

Comment: That may be, but the OP specifically asked how to retrieve from a **function**  , not from whatever `magrittr` or `pipeR` does with closures.